# Spark AR Studio how to move object after 3 seconds patch editor

Tags: apache-spark, augmented-reality

I’ve successfully used a target tracker in Spark AR Studio with a simple plane object as a child of the target tracker to view in AR. When I view the target tracker with my phone, the plane is visible.

Simple enough, but I’m having trouble using the patch editor to move that plane after a specified amount of time, say 3 seconds. I’ve looked through documentation and couldn’t really find anything related to my issue. It’d be much appreciated if someone could help me figure out how to move this plane object after 3 seconds to a different location on my target tracker.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways it can be done. One way would be use the Runtime patch to get the current time, and a Greater Than patch to trigger an animation when the time passes 3 seconds.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use the loop node and set the duration to 3s and connect the 'completed' output to the interactive node/object

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).